# Printing a two-dimensional array Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a task, to fill up a two-dimensional array in a specific way, so it should make an output like shown on the picture, for example:

`1 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 1`

This is what I did and it works fine:

```
public class TwoDArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FillUpTwoDArray(7, 7);
    }

    public static void FillUpTwoDArrays(int rows, int columns) {
        int twoD[][] = new int[rows][columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                twoD[i][j] = 0;
                if (i == j) {
                    twoD[i][j] = 1;
                }
                if (i + j == rows - 1) {
                    twoD[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

My headache starts here:

`1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1`

Maybe logic looks obvious for someone, but I have no clue at all, how to explain this to JVM. I don't ask you for a solution-ready answer, some hints would be perfect, thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your code already working?  If the second image is what you currently have, then yes, your code is working, in which case your question probably belongs on our sister site, [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What‘s the difference between both pictures?

Comment: I actually can't see the problem.

Comment: The second picture is incorrect. They are just getting an "X" of 1s through the 2D array, instead of the two complete triangles.

Comment: @Lynx 
Sorry! Messed up little bit, uploaded right pictures

Comment: @gpicchiarelli the problem is that I can't understand how to explain to JVM how to fill up a 2D-array in a way, shown on the second picture..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, my code is working for the first picture, but I need some help with the second one, should I go to CRSE then ?

Comment: Hint: use 3 loops per row. One to go from 0 to k, filling with 0. One to go from k to rows - k, filling with 1. One to go from rows - k to rows, filling with 0. Try finding the value of k at each iteration: it depends on the value of i. And since the result should always be a square, you should pass a single argument (rows) to your method, not two.

Comment: @artshakhov No, if it's not working for the second picture and you want it to work for the second picture, it's not ready for review on CRSE.

Comment: Think about the center and offset. So in 7x7, center is (0,0) and top left would be (-3,-3) or (0-3,0-3) with offset.

Comment: In the original post you had this image too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OwEp.png, but now the question shows https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gbn6.png twice. Please review which one is which.

Comment: @tevemadar Just replaced with characters.. Idk what's wrong happening with pictures every time.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you need to do is attack the other boundary conditions that exist within the diagonals that you're already printing. The first boundary is defined as the area where the column index is greater than the row index, but less than the row's length minus the row index:

```
for (int k = j; k < twoD[i].length - i; k++) {
    if (k > i) {
        twoD[i][k] = 1;
    }
}
```

The lower portion of the triangle is a bit tougher. The boundary there is defined as the area where the column index is between the row index, and the length of the row, minus the row index, minus 1:

```
for (int h = j; h < twoD[i].length; h++) {
    if (h < i && j > (rows - i - 1)) {
        twoD[i][h] = 1;
    }
}
```

Placed altogether with the rest of your code, the solution (or rather, a solution; I don't claim that this is optimized) would be:

```
public class TwoDArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FillUpTwoDArrays(7, 7);
    }

    public static void FillUpTwoDArrays(int rows, int columns) {
        int twoD[][] = new int[rows][columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                twoD[i][j] = 0;

                for (int k = j; k < twoD[i].length - i; k++) {
                    if (k > i) {
                        twoD[i][k] = 1;
                    }
                }

                if (i == j) {
                    twoD[i][j] = 1;
                }

                if (i + j == rows - 1) {
                    twoD[i][j] = 1;
                }

                for (int h = j; h < twoD[i].length; h++) {
                    if (h < i && j > (rows - i - 1)) {
                        twoD[i][h] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn, how can you be so smart? Thanks, sir!

Comment: Happy to help! My approach is usually to break down the problem into smaller digestible parts. Once they are solved on the small scale, it's just a matter of combining them back together to solve the complete problem.